# virtualenv activation: No command 'Script' found

Tags: virtualenv

Ubuntu 14.04

My virtualenv worked. But now I can't activate it.
I get this result:

```
michael@michael:~$ source venv/gmv_venv/bin/activate
No command 'Script' found, did you mean:
 Command 'script' from package 'bsdutils' (main)
Script: command not found
]0: command not found
michael@michael:: command not found
]0: command not found
michael@michael:: command not found
]0: command not found
michael@michael:: command not found
]0: command not found
michael@michael:: command not found
]0: command not found
michael@michael:: command not found
[01: command not found
: command not found
[01: command not found
: command not found
[01: command not found
: command not found
[01: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
[01: command not found
: command not found
bash: venv/gmv_venv/bin/activate: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Could you help me understand what have I done wrongly and what to do to repair.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved!

It seems that the **"./bin/activate"** file has been **overwritten**.
You can **replace your *activate* file with the following script**.
Remember to replace the env name with your environment name in line number 49
i.e

> VIRTUAL_ENV='/root/env/arshad'   **to ->**   '/root/env/your_env_name'

**script** -

```
# This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
# you cannot run it directly


if [ "${BASH_SOURCE-}" = "$0" ]; then
    echo "You must source this script: \$ source $0" >&2
    exit 33
fi

deactivate () {
    unset -f pydoc >/dev/null 2>&1

    # reset old environment variables
    # ! [ -z ${VAR+_} ] returns true if VAR is declared at all
    if ! [ -z "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH:+_}" ] ; then
        PATH="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH"
        export PATH
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH
    fi
    if ! [ -z "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME+_}" ] ; then
        PYTHONHOME="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME"
        export PYTHONHOME
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME
    fi

    # This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
    # be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
    # past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
    if [ -n "${BASH-}" ] || [ -n "${ZSH_VERSION-}" ] ; then
        hash -r 2>/dev/null
    fi

    if ! [ -z "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1+_}" ] ; then
        PS1="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1"
        export PS1
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1
    fi

    unset VIRTUAL_ENV
    if [ ! "${1-}" = "nondestructive" ] ; then
    # Self destruct!
        unset -f deactivate
    fi
}

# unset irrelevant variables
deactivate nondestructive

VIRTUAL_ENV='/root/env/arshad'
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH

# unset PYTHONHOME if set
if ! [ -z "${PYTHONHOME+_}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME="$PYTHONHOME"
    unset PYTHONHOME
fi

if [ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT-}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="${PS1-}"
    if [ "x" != x ] ; then
        PS1="${PS1-}"
    else
        PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`) ${PS1-}"
    fi
    export PS1
fi

# Make sure to unalias pydoc if it's already there
alias pydoc 2>/dev/null >/dev/null && unalias pydoc || true

pydoc () {
    python -m pydoc "$@"
}

# This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
# be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
# past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
if [ -n "${BASH-}" ] || [ -n "${ZSH_VERSION-}" ] ; then
    hash -r 2>/dev/null
fi
```

**In case this doesn't work-**
(It might be the case that the version of virtualenv I am using is different from yours.)
**You can get the script that is compatible with your version by -**
making a new dummy virtualenv and copying the contents of the dummy_env/bin/activate file to your_env/bin/actiavte and replace the env name with your_env.